# On a subring of the Laurent polynomials ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and consider the Laurent polynomials ring $S:= R[x,x^{-1}]$ and a polynomial $f\in S$. Suppose that $f$ is invertible in $S$ and $f\in R[x+x^{-1}]$. Is it true that $f^{-1}$ belongs to $R[x+x^{-1}]$? The article I am reading claims that $R[x+x^{-1}]\cong R[y]$ but I can not see why. So please help me to understand this isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

$R[x+x^{-1}]$ is by definition the image of the morphism
$$
\Phi:R[y]\to R[x,x^{-1}]
$$
determined by $\Phi(y)=x+x^{-1}$. We have to show that this morphism is injective. Else, there would exist a $P\ne 0$ in $R[y]$ such that $P(x+x^{-1})=0$. But now let us consider the principal term of $P$ in $P=c_ny^n+$ lower terms, $c_n\ne 0$ in $R$, then $P(x+x^{-1})=c_nx^n+$ lower terms, this is not zero, so $\Phi(P)\ne 0$, contradiction.

Comment: The last line is not quit correct, unless you work in $R[x,x^{-1}]$. However, by multiplying $P(x+x^{-1})$ by $x^n$ everything is restored in $R[x]$, and easily proven.

Comment: I am starting with $P\ne 0$ in $R[y]$, map it to $\Phi(P)\in R[x,x^{-1}]$, then $\Phi(P)\in S$ is (universality, we compute $P$ it in the element $x+x^{-1}$ of $S$) $\Phi(P)=P(x+x^{-1})=c_n(x+x^{-1})^n+$ something in the linear span of $x^k$ for powers $k$ with $-n<k<n$, so the only contribution in $x^n$ comes from  $c_n(x+x^{-1})^n$ and it is $c_nx^n\ne 0$.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned this argument when I said "unless you work in $R[x,x^{-1}]$". But people are less familiar with Laurent polynomials and it's easily understood if one works in $R[x]$ instead.